# Fininshed rendering layer event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am using google maps api v3 to create a map with a couple of layers that are loaded after users' request. The layers are loaded using Geojson format with the code below

```
function getgeojson(json) 
    {            
        proplayer = new google.maps.Data();
        proplayer.loadGeoJson('../public/geoprop/index');
        proplayer.setStyle({  
                               fillColor: 'red',
                               strokeColor: 'red',
                               fillOpacity: 0.3,
                               strokeWeight: 1
                            });
         proplayer.setMap(map);                 
         proplayer.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {                                   
                                infoWindow.setContent(event.feature.getProperty('kta'));
                                infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                                infoWindow.open(map);
                            });     

    }
```

The layers consist of 3.5 K polygons approximately with simple geometry (almost all of them are rectangular shapes) and it takes about 5 sec to be  fully rendered in the map. I want  to use a loader indicator while the layer is rendered so I use two functions

```
ajaxindicatorstart('loading data.. please wait..');
ajaxindicatorstop();
```

to start and stop the indicator. The problem is that I cannot detect when the rendering is completed. I have tried

```
proplayer.addListener( 'metadata_changed', function () {ajaxindicatorstop();});
```

and

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
                                            ajaxindicatorstop();
                            });
```

suggested by other users but it didn't work.  Is this actually possible? Are there are any alternatives to bypass this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possible approach may be:

1. load the JSON via AJAX instead of `loadGeoJson`
2. get the number of features in the requested JSON and store it in a variable
3. observe the `addfeature`-event of the layer(details at the end)
4. add the features to the layer via `addGeoJson`

In the `addfeature`-handler you may decrement the stored number of features (step 2) , when it's `0` all features have been added.

Comment: I just added     proplayer.addListener( 'addfeature', function () {ajaxindicatorstop();}); in getgeojson function and works like a charm. I will investigate further for the solution you proposed but everything seems to work fine for now. Thank you very much.